# how to iterate a list like List<Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, foreach

I have a method which is returning `List<Map<String,Object>>`.

How to iterate over a list like  `List<Map<String,Object>>`?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: If you have the choice, try to avoid overly complex nested collection datastructures like this one in favor of creating a new class. If another programmer encounters your List<Map<String,Object>> he will probably have to delve into your code to find out that it contains exactly. With a class you can make your intentions clear with naming and documentation.

Answer (score 35):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list; // this is what you have already

for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a very detailed and easy to understand answer. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = getMyMap();    
for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

1. Loop through list of maps
2. Handle map entries

Comment: You have a few typos. You're assigning `map` twice and the values from the list should be `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 6):

with java 1.8 (8) you can re-write it like:

```
list.forEach(item -> 
                item.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + (String)v)
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting you one simple Example of `List<Map<String,Object>>`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("Map1 Key1", (Object) "Map1 value1");
    map1.put("Map1 Key2", (Object) "Map1 value2");

    Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("Map2 Key1", (Object) "Map2 value1");
    map2.put("Map2 Key2", (Object) "Map2 value2");

    List<Map<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(map1);
    list.add(map2);

    list.stream().forEach(mapsData->{
        mapsData.entrySet().forEach(mapData->{
            System.out.println("Key:"+mapData.getKey()+ " Value:"+mapData.getValue());
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = ...

for (Map<String, Object> map : list)
{
     ...
}
```

You can also use an [iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) or the [get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method within a for loop to access the elements within the List.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("First", "1");
    map.put("Second", "2");
    map.put("third", "3");
    map.put("four", "4");

    // here is the logic 
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Question is about iterating through List of Maps, not just a Map.  I would down vote this, but you lose a point by doing this.

Comment: Thanks bro . Good suggestion

Comment: Not answering the question, downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to iterate over a list of Maps as my starting point.  My List had one Map object inside with 3 values

```
List<Map<String, Object>>
```

using Java's functional programming in a rather short and succinct manner.    The purpose here was to pull out all the maps stored in a list and print them out.  I could have also collected the values etc.

```
answerListOfMaps.stream().map(map -> map.entrySet())
        .forEach(System.out::println );
```

output in Eclipse IDE console looked like this:

```
[isAllowed=true, isValid=true, cardNumber=672xxxxxxxxxxx]
```

x's for Obfuscation

alternate way:

```
answerListOfMaps.stream().flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .forEach( entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue()) );
```

console:

```
isAllowed:true
isValid:true
cardNumber:672xxxxxxxxxxx
```